# Ionic appdev crash after a native http post (or get)

Tags: http, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-devapp, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

I'm using the native http of cordova to make an http Post and my devapp (in my mobile) crash !
I tried the [solution](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator/issues/207?fbclid=IwAR0xCpLfX3aaq9ODvtCpjTACzROknZ8FeWPOrlZSByLuQ56yghlHFqJaMC0) to change the OKHTTP_VERSION, but it dosent work.

I tried to execute the comand bellow

```
cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator --variable OKHTTP_VERSION=3.10.0
```

But it dosen't work. Did any one try this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

On the below page there is a section for native Cordova plugin supported in DevApp and unfortunately, HTTP native is not supported in DevApp.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp/

Comment: in this page there is a section who talk about "Use the Advanced HTTP plugin".
And the section who talk about native Cordova plugin supported, there is : 

> cordova-plugin-advanced-http 1.8.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
May be because i'm not using the good version of the plugin.
FI : i'm using Ionic 4